# Вывод видео в отзывах вместе с изображениями - php wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, видео, img

Пытаюсь настроить отображение в отзывах фото и видео, которые добавляют клиенты.
Часть кода, который отвечает за загрузку фото и видео материалов поправила, а вот с отображением видео не могу разобраться. Очень прошу о помощи.
Сейчас настроено так:

```
<div class="row comment-row">
    <div class="unit-comment-name col-xs-12 ">
        <p><?= $comment->comment_author ?></p>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="unit-comment col-xs-12 ">
        <p><?= $comment->comment_content ?></p>
        <div class="unit-comment-box-inner">
            <div class="unit-comment-img"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 review-attachments">
    <?php
        //attachmentId
        $attachments = get_comment_meta($comment->comment_ID, 'attachmentId', FALSE);
        foreach ($attachments as $attachment) {
            if (wp_attachment_is_image($attachment)) {
                $link = wp_get_attachment_url($attachment);
    ?>
                <a target="_blank" href="<?= $link ?>" data-fancybox="gallery-4280" data-lightbox="group4280" class="review-img">
                    <div style="height: 80px; display: inline-block">
                        <img src="<?= $link ?>" style="height: 100%; width: auto">
                    </div>
                </a>
    <?
            }
        }
    //
    ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Так а с чем конкретно Вы не разобрались? Вот Вам пример с [видео](https://codepen.io/fancyapps/pen/GXVLyr)

Comment: В качестве комментариев/отзывов загружаю на сайт фото и видео. Фото - отображаются нормально, а видео не отображаются совсем(

Comment: Ну наверное потому что не стоит ссылку на видео передавать в тег `img`.